# DNS settings on computers and switches

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internet

Noob questions.

I have static IPs on many of my Windows computers in our Windows 2008 domain. In the network settings at each, I have an a static IP and subnet. The default Gateway is set to our Sonicwall.

**Question:** Under DNS servers, do I just list the Server IP? I've found this works fine on XP through Win7, but Win8 needs an alternate DNS to get to the Internet. (using 8.8.8.8). Do I need to list the Server IP at all?

Answer (score 4):

All computers that are members of an Active Directory domain should *only* have DNS servers running on Domain Controller (DC) computers specified (unless you *really* know why you're doing otherwise).

The DNS Client in Windows 8 doesn't operate appreciably differently than in recent prior versions of Windows. I'd spend some time investigating (with Wireshark, or some such) what queries are coming from the Windows 8 clients to your DNS server, and what the responses back look like. Spend some time with the `nslookup` command, too, just for starts to see what responses for queries to Internet names look like there.